# Why is it showing that the variable is not empty when I print it, but it returns empty when printing the variable and other words?

Tags: python

I have a variable that reads values from a file. It doesn't return empty when I just print the variable, but it returns empty when I print the variable and other words. This is really weird.

My code:

```
f = open(file, "r")
print("f.read(): " + f.read()) // Successfully returns the text in the file
print('"ABC" + f.read() + "ABC": ' + "ABC" + f.read() + "ABC") // Unexpected return ""ABC" + f.read() + "ABC": ABCABC"
```

Why is there such a strange thing? How to solve this problem? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: after you call `f.read()` the first time, it reads the whole file.  Unless you close and reopen the file or seek back to the beginning, the next `f.read()` returns nothing because you're at the end of the file.

Comment: The first time you call it, `f.read()` reads the entire file.  The next time you call it the file is at `EOF` so it returns an empty string.  You should either assign it to a variable when you call it the first time, or rewind the file if you want to read it again.